# Issue with Facebook Analytics results

Tags: android, facebook, analytics

I have published the application on Google Play and noticed that in Facebook Analytics 0 day shows 60-70% retention. But other system of analytics such as Flurry and Firebase show me 100% of 0 day.

I can also see the installation of tokens in my database on a server that is added only if the user launches the application. And they do not correspond to the data that is in the analytics of Facebook.

First, the old version of the SDK was integrated, but after the update seems that the situation has not changed. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook measures retention using two events. Thats why when you manually add a cohort report it asks for two event types. Typically people choose App Launch and App Launch which I think is what Facebook uses for their prebuilt “retention” report.

If users only launch your app once on day zero, then they will not be counted because there was no second “App Launch” event sent.  Your retention will be less than 100%.

If you make a cohort report using *App Install* for the first event and *App Launch* for the second event, you’ll see you always get 100% day zero retention.

Answer (score 0):

In case it wasn't coming from your SDK integration, did you check the "retention" section or "cohorts" ?

In retention, you should have 100% on day 0 as it tracks people who use your app. It's binary as either you use or not, so you're in or out. That being said, you must have 100% on day 0 as soon you get 1 user using your app or bot. On days you have no user, you should find 0% on day 0.

However, if you check the "cohorts" section, not having 100% on day 0 totally makes sense : FAfA tracks users from the first event to see how many of them will perform the second event. Let's say your cohort tracks new users who then buy something, you'll have new users everyday (hopefully!) but not 100% of them will purchase you something on day 0. It could happen but it's not guaranteed :) So most of the time, you'll get on day 0 a lower percentage than 100%.